# Object reference not set to an instance of the object;

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController2D controller;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    private float horizontalMove = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")*runSpeed;
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        controller.Move(horizontalMove*Time.fixedDeltaTime,false,false);//error is somewhere here
    }
}
```

Though all the classes are defines it throws the error
please help!!!!!

Comment: In this case, I would expect error to be caused because "controller" is null(unassigned).

Comment: No @Nick i have assigned a controller in the inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you've assigned a valid component into your `controller` field in the inspector before running your game.

If you've looked and you're sure it's there, then you might accidentally have another instance of this `PlayerMovement` script somewhere else in your scene. Add a `Debug.Log` to print out the name of the object in `Start()` to help track down the spare, uninitialized instance.

Also, note that capturing horizontal input in `Update()`, saving it to a variable then using it in the next `FixedUpdate()` will add at least one unnecessary frame of latency to your input, since `Update()` runs after `FixedUpdate()` in a frame. Instead, you can read and use your axis input in `FixedUpdate()` directly to get the latest info "hot off the presses." ;)

I've seen advice claiming that the latest input isn't available until `Update()`, but experimentally this is not true for any version of Unity I've tested. It might be superstition left over from an older version, or an over-application of the rule to not naively handle *instantaneous* inputs (eg. button down events that happen for only one frame) in `FixedUpdate()` since it can miss or double-handle them. This is easy to work around though, so lag is usually unnecessary there too.